# PrimeFaces 3.2 Picklist : Getting Target-List On JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

How to Traverse Picklist - TargetList and update the target list values to a ManagedBean List by using java script function.

Note: The version I am working not support ajax transfer event, I need to use onTransfer

Below my code.

```
 <p:pickList id="pickListId" value="#{bean.legacySystem}" 
 onTransfer="bindTargetValues();" var="legacySys" widgetVar="pickListWV" 
 itemLabel="#{legacySys}" itemValue="#{legacySys}"/> 


<script>
function bindTargetValues(){
//How to traverse and bind tragetList values to a managed bean object
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access in the JavaScript the content of the both lists, there are hidden selects, suffixed with "_source" and "target".

So, `$('[id$=pickListId_source] option')` will return you all `option` elements representing the source list, and `$('[id$=pickListId_target] option')` the same, with target.

Than you can iterate the options and read `value` attribute to check which elements are in which list.